# Display density() graph with date in x axis using R

Tags: r, date, graph, label

I have a partial success with

```
input = "date,data
1-1-2015,5.5
2-1-2016,1.0
3-1-2016,4.0
4-1-2016,4.0
5-1-2019,3.0"
new = read.csv(text=input)
new$date = as.Date(new$date, "%d-%m-%Y")
new$date = as.numeric(new$date, as.Date("2015-01-01"), units="days") #https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-May/162719.html
plot(density(new$date))
```

Resulting in working graph, unfortunately x axis is obviously formatted as integers. How can I produce graph with x axis formatted as data?

I expected

```
new = read.csv(text=input)
new$date = as.Date(new$date, "%d-%m-%Y")
plot(density(new$date))
```

to work, unfortunately it crashed with `Error in density.default(new$date) : argument 'x' must be numeric`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`density()` wasn't really optimized to work with dates. The easiest fix would probably be to just replace the default axis labeling with date values. Here's how you can do that

```
plot(density(new$date), xaxt="n")
at<-axTicks(1)
axis(1,at, as.Date(at, origin="1970-01-01"))
```

[image]